# Removing "" elements in a ArrayList

Tags: c#

I have this arraylist:

```
ArrayList ftd = new ArrayList();
ftd.Add(new string[]{ "foo1.txt", "01.01.2011" });
ftd.Add(new string[]{ "foo2.txt", "04.01.2011" });
ftd.Add(new string[]{ "foo3.txt", "09.01.2011" });
```

and after some logic the arraylist looks something like this:

```
[0] = { "foo1.txt", "01.01.2011" }
[1] = { "", "04.01.2011" }
[2] = { "foo3.txt", "09.01.2011" }
```

NOW: how do i loop thru ftd and remove elements there the elements first var is ""?

Comment: it will be helpfull if u use the Length variable of each array in the arraylist, u can compare the length and where the length of array is equal to 1 u can remove that.

Comment: Note that storing dates as string is ALWAYS bad practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this:

```
var result = ftd.Cast<string[]>().Where(x => x[0] != "");
```

Comment: It does not remove the elements from the list, this creates a copy of the list without some elements.

Comment: @GvS: Right you are. I interpreted "Remove" not literal in the meaning of "use the same instance".

Answer (score 4):

Try something like:

```
var filteredFtd = ftd.Cast<string[]>().Where(a => false == a[0].Equals(""));
```

If you don't want to change ftd in-place.

If you do want to change it in place, you can use RemoveAll as suggested in other answers.

**BTW**: I'd use a a [List< T >](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) from System.Collections.Generic instead. Type safety can save you from silly bugs often, and also removes the requirement to cast to a magically-known type (you have to remember what the correct type will be, otherwise you'll hit runtime exceptions). The code would like something like:

```
var ftd = new List<string[]>();
ftd.Add(new string[]{ "foo1.txt", "01.01.2011" });
ftd.Add(new string[]{ "foo2.txt", "04.01.2011" });
ftd.Add(new string[]{ "foo3.txt", "09.01.2011" });

var filteredFtd = ftd.Where(a => false == a[0].Equals(""));
```

Comment: just curious, why do you use `false == expr` instead of `!expr` ?

Comment: jb: it's harder to miss when reading the code. !something can slip through reviews, false == something is less likely to get ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using LINQ to modify the list:

```
var results = from string[] s in ftd
              where s[0] != ""
              select s;
ftd = new ArrayList(results.ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Both examples will remove items from the list, without making a copy of the list.

I also prefer the use of `string.IsNullOrEmpty` for the check. It makes your code more clear, and checks for a possible `null`.

*My preferred method*: If you could use a `List<string[]>` you could use:

```
var ftd = new List<string[]>();
// Logic to fill & handle

// To remove
ftd.RemoveAll(a => string.IsNullOrEmpty(a[0]));
```

And you would be somewhat more typesafe.

If you cannot change the type. You can loop through the list using a counter, instead of using the iterator (foreach):

```
for(int i = 0; i < ftd.Count; i++) {
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(arr[0])) {
      ftd.RemoveAt(i);
      i--; // Adjust for One less
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're after a non-LINQ method, one option would be to loop through it and copy all the other elements to a new list:

```
ArrayList ftd2 = new ArrayList();

foreach(object element in ftd)
{
    string [] str = (string[])element;
    if(str[0] != "")
        ftd2.add(str);
}
```

Something like that. Untested code but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for something like

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayList ftd = new ArrayList();
        ftd.Add(new string[] { "foo1.txt", "01.01.2011" });
        ftd.Add(new string[] { "", "04.01.2011" });
        ftd.Add(new string[] { "foo3.txt", "09.01.2011" });

        var result = ftd.Cast<string[]>().Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x[0]));
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

try it

ArrayList ftd = new ArrayList();

```
    ftd.Add(new string[] { "foo1.txt", "01.01.2011" });

    ftd.Add(new string[] { "", "04.01.2011" });

    ftd.Add(new string[] { "foo3.txt", "09.01.2011" });

    ArrayList ftd1 = new ArrayList();

    foreach (object str in ftd)
    {
        string[] arr =(string[]) str;
        if (!arr[0].Split(',')[0].Equals(""))
        {
            ftd1.Add(str);
        }              
    }
```

Comment: The `Split` doesn't make any sense.